# groovy grails build test data (buildtestdata plugin) how to create many to many

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails

With Grails 2.2.4.  and build-test-data:2.0.5.  I'm failing at adding a many-to-many instance in the DB using conf - Bootstrap.groovy.  Using MySQL as the database.

Here's the simplified domain classes:

```
class Reseller {
String resellerName
static hasMany = [addresses: Address]
```

}

and

```
class Address {
String address1 
static hasMany = [resellers: Reseller]
static belongsTo = [Reseller]
```

}

which results in this being created in MySQL when ran...

(a simple ER diagram below since I can't post images from MySQL Workbench Diagram)

reseller ==> 1 to many==>  reseller_address <== many to 1 <== address

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `address` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `address1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reseller` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `reseller_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reseller_addresses` (
  `address_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `reseller_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reseller_id`,`address_id`),
  KEY `FK3F39FB15CB44906F` (`reseller_id`),
  KEY `FK3F39FB1541937EA5` (`address_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `reseller_addresses`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK3F39FB1541937EA5` FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES `address` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK3F39FB15CB44906F` FOREIGN KEY (`reseller_id`) REFERENCES `reseller` (`id`);

Here's the Bootstrap.groovy:

```
    import grails.buildtestdata.mixin.Build
import manytomany.*

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        Address ad1 = Address.build()
        Reseller rs1 = Reseller.build()

        //comment out next line to run and see tables being built.
        rs1.addToAddresses(address: ad1) //does not work.  see error below                      
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

And the above results in the error below.  It also results in zero tables in the DB over in MySQL.  I can see them get created and then they disappear at the error below.

```
    | Running Grails application
Hibernate: insert into address (version, address1) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into reseller (version, reseller_name) values (?, ?)
| Error 2013-11-13 17:37:01,543 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hibernate.AssertionFailure  - an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)
Message: null id in manytomany.Address entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2013-11-13 17:37:01,628 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: null id in manytomany.Address entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
Message: null id in manytomany.Address entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way, you can pass your associations to the parent class through `.build(...)`:

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    Address ad1 = Address.build()
    Reseller rs1 = Reseller.build(addresses:[ad1])
}
```

documentation : https://github.com/tednaleid/build-test-data/wiki/SampleCode

Comment: THANKS! That worked - BUT I do NOT see that sort of example in the Sample Code, anywere.  Am I missing it?  Can you point me to Grails docs that discuss how the [brackets] around [ad1] work - and what they mean? (I can guess what they mean, but being new to Grails, it's just so darn hard to find explanations).  I had tried: Reseller rs1 = Reseller.build(addresses:ad1) without the brackets and it failed (though I typo'd it in the question above).

Comment: addresses is a list, so I just put `ad1` in a list. On the link I posted look at where it says `// build the issue first` , its building the issue and then pass it into Page domain, except in your case it was a list.

Comment: Ahhh- a List.  And the brackets are the syntax for the List... THANKS!! Here's the docs...http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections.  Now, it's clear.